# chrome webkit - tabs permissions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

When I add the permissions of "tabs" to my manifest file and then load the unpacked extension, I receive the following error message: "Access to permission "tabs" denied." I am using Chrome v.17.0.963.56 m

Comment: Can you give your manifest file?

Comment: If your manifest looks like what Mohamed noted below, and you're still getting the error, please file a bug at http://new.crbug.com/, post the ID here, and we'll make sure it lands in the correct queue.

Comment: I have posted it to new.crbug.com. The issue number is 116979.

Comment: I have replied back to that bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your manifest is structured correctly. Something like this:

```
{
  ...
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  ...
}
```

It must be within that permission, try to reload more than once, sometimes version 17 is flaky where the permissions do not reload.

Remember, that tabs is only available through Extensions, not [Apps](http://code.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide.html#manifest). So your most likely getting an error because your packaging it up as an app instead of an extension (You have an "app" attribute in your manifest"

Comment: Here is my manifest:`{
  "name": "Name",
  "description": "Description",
  "version": "1",
  "app": {
    "urls": [
  "https://www.mydomain.com/foldername/"
 ],
    "launch": {
        "web_url": "https://www.mydomain.com/foldername/"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "tabs",
    "notifications",
 "background"
  ],
  "background_page": "https://www.mydomain.com/foldername/page.asp"
}`

Comment: I've tried to upload multiple times and always get the error. If I remove the tabs and keep the other permissions it loads fine.

Comment: I see the problem, your making it an *app*, you cannot use the tabs permissions for "apps". For apps, you can use combination of "background", "clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite", "geolocation", "notifications", and "unlimitedStorage". That is all.